# git push origin master gives error permission denied (github)

Tags: git, ssh, github, key

> ERROR: Permission to durrantm/linker.git **denied** to kevinzen.
>   fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly

I've tried a lot of things to change/set my identity and get rid of that 'kevinzen'

**Update - final resolution was that I had added my public key... but... I had missed a few characters so it was invalid.  Pasting in the correct key on github fixed it**

I have `~/.ssh/` with files

- `config`
- `id_dsa`
- `id_dsa.pub`
- `id_kb_rsa`
- `id_kb_rsa.pub`
- `id_rsa`
- `id_rsa.pub`
- `known_hosts`

I have done

```
git config --global user.name
git config --global user.email
git remote add origin git@github.com:durrantm/linker.git
```

I have added my local ssh key with my info (not kevinz) for this machine to github ssh keys.

I also tried: 
`ssh git@github.com.
The authenticity of host 'github.com. (207.97.227.239)' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is 16:27:ac:a5:76:28:2d:36:63:1b:56:4d:eb:df:a6:48.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
Warning: Permanently added 'github.com.' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
PTY allocation request failed on channel 0`

wasn't sure about the PTY error.  Still stuck.

Comment: Is your public key registered here: https://github.com/account/ssh ? Can you double-check?

Comment: Have you checked the files in `~/.ssh` for any mentions of kevinzen?

Comment: I checked, cat'd the files and `cat * | grep kevinzen` but nothing found.  strange.

Comment: I also have the PTY channel error when ssh'ing to git@github.com, but it puts this message below: `Hi bgarret! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.`? I assume you don't have this?

Comment: Also, this is far fetched, but it could be that kevinzen added your ssh public key to his acocunt...

Comment: Hi Benoit yes I did see that.  I think I have resolved my issue - I had added my key... but I had missed a few characters.  Also yes on kevinzen I think that's my business partner's name and I will check with him.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Did you install your key at GitHub? Have you read help section there?

- https://help.github.com/articles/reviewing-your-ssh-keys/
- https://github.com/settings/keys

You can list [your own keys as saved at GitHub](https://github.com/settings/keys) by:

```
curl https://github.com/<username>.keys
```

Have you checked that one of the keys is a match to one of your keys? Compare:

```
cat ~/.ssh/id_*.pub
```

Comment: Good question.  Yes I had added my local ssh key to github but the issue remained.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem, my solution was simple.  I already have my keys setup and everything and kept trying to run:

```
git config --global user.name IceMupppet
```

After looking through my ~/.ssh/ I noticed that running:

```
ssh-add -l
```

I saw that to simply use the right git account I just added the right file:

```
ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_IceMupppet_rsa
```

... then a `git push origin master`  worked fine.  I have an alias on my ssh config to use different keys for my work and personal, but still had to do this step for some reason.